# ELCImagePickerController without allowing access to user location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image-gallery, alasset

I used ELCImagePickerController in my app.
but when we start our application first time and on Image gallery it will ask for accessing user location , if we don't allow to access user location to it then it will give error in UIAlertView and it wont show image gallery.

But after that if we go to setting app -> location services -> [turn on switch for access location for our app] then start app -> go to gallery page -> we can show image gallery in our app.

So my question is how can we show image gallery with ELCImagePickerController with location services turn off for our app or user don't allow to access location to our app.
ELCImagePickerController can be downloadable at this [LINK](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)

Then find ELCAlbumPickerController.m file then go to View Did Load then this causes error alert when user location access turned off,

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Group enumerator Block
    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if (group == nil) 
        {
            return;
        }

        [self.assetGroups addObject:group];

        // Keep this line!  w/o it the asset count is broken for some reason.  Makes no sense
        NSLog(@"count: %d", [group numberOfAssets]);

        // Reload albums
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    };

    // Group Enumerator Failure Block
    void (^assetGroupEnumberatorFailure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Album Error: %@", [error description]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        NSLog(@"A problem occured %@", [error description]);                                     
    };  

    // Enumerate Albums
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];        
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator 
                         failureBlock:assetGroupEnumberatorFailure];


    [library release];
    [pool release];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you can't show the image gallery with ELCImagePickerController with location services turned off.

ELCImagePickerController uses the Assets Library Framework to access the device's photo album. Because this framework also gives access to the metadata of the photos - including location data - the user needs to grant permission for the app to use Location Services.

There's no way around this, except if you use the standard UIImagePickerController (but I assume that won't cover the requirements for your app)

Comment: if the user denied the access,it does not loads images from assets,but i want to ask access again when he loads ELCImagePickerController how can i do this one